# Como esconder/mostrar uma div em HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, div

Como faço um JavaScript que mostre/esconda uma div em HTML?

Tentei tipo:

```
function Mudarestado(divid)
{
    var disp = document.getElementById(divid).style.display;
    disp = "none;" // (ou disp = "block")
}
```

mas isso não funcionou.

Comment: Nathan, confira como funciona o markdown aqui no SOPT: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As soluções abaixo darão um caminho de como implementar em diversas situações.

**Javascript puro**

```js
function Mudarestado(el) {
        var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
        if(display == "none")
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
        else
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
    }
```

```html
<div id="minhaDiv">Conteudo</div>
<button type="button" onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv')">Mostrar / Esconder</button>
```

**Solução em JQuery**

```js
$(function(){
        $(".btn-toggle").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            el = $(this).data('element');
            $(el).toggle();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="minhaDiv">Conteudo</div>
<button type="button" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#minhaDiv">Mostrar / Esconder</button>
```

**Angular JS**

```js
angular.module("ExemploApp", [])
```

```html
<body ng-app="ExemploApp">

  <div id="minhaDiv" ng-init="MinhaDiv = true" ng-show="MinhaDiv">Conteudo</div>
  <button type="button" ng-click="MinhaDiv = !MinhaDiv">Mostrar / Esconder</button>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Vue**

```js
var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        mostrar: true,
        oi: "xuxa"
      },
      
      methods: {
        mostrarEsconder() {
          this.mostrar = !this.mostrar
        }
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="mostrarEsconder">mostrar/esconder</button>
  <div v-if="mostrar">Minha Div Com v-if</div>
  <div v-show="mostrar">Minha Div Com v-show</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nesse caso o conteúdo ja inicia exibindo,  como  fazer que ele inicie oculto?

Comment: Você pode usar getElementsByClassName para pegar o elemento tbm. Ah, vc cria a variável display mas não usou, rs.

Answer (score 8):

Sua variável `disp` está apenas recebendo uma **CÓPIA do valor atual** do atributo "display". Alterar o valor da variável **não** mudará o valor deste atributo "display".

Portanto, sua função deveria ser assim:

```
function Mudarestado(divid)
{
    document.getElementById(divid).style.display = "none"; // ou "block"
}
```

Comment: a sim agora entendo. em disp só era um meio deu recolher o estado do objeto mas não definilo. muito obrigado.

Answer (score 7):

Se você quer uma função que mostre quando está escondido, e esconda quando está visível (ou seja, um *toggle*), faça assim:

```
function toggleEstado(divid) {
    var div = document.getElementById(divid);
    var disp = div.style.display;
    div.style.display = disp == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

Comment: usei o seguinte código e mesmo assim não functionou:

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 functon mudar(id){ document.getElementById(id).display.style = 'none'; }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="mudar('footerx');">Mostra/oCULTAR fOOTER</a>
<div id="footerx">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('file:///C:/', '_new');">Disco Local C:</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Esse código (que só oculta a div, não é o que eu postei) tem 2 erros: falta um `i` em `function`, e você usou `display.style`  em vez de `style.display`.

Answer (score 3):

Talvez sejam apenas alguns erros de sintaxe.
Veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
document.getElementById("minhadiv").style.display = 'none';
```

Nesse caso, minhadiv é o id da div.

Comment: Não, tanto "aspas simples" ('') com "aspas duplas" ("") são string em javascript.

Comment: a sim agora entendi. valeu mesmo

Comment: essa funcionou

<pre>
function Mudarestado(el) {
    var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
    if(display == "none")
        document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
    else
        document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
}
</pre>

Answer (score 2):

Usando [jQuery](http://jquery.com), a função seria algo assim:

```
$('ID_DA_DIV').hide();
```

Se quiser que já carregue invisivel use CSS para isso usando `display: none`.

Com jQuery

```
$('ID_DA_DIV').css("display", "none")
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript é muito poderosa e podemos desfrutar de diversas funcionalidades da linguagem

Conforme dito em uma das repostas anteriores, sua variável **disp** está recebendo o valor do display

```
function Mudarestado(divid) {
    var disp = document.getElementById(divid).style.display;
    disp = "none"; // (ou disp = "block")
 }
```

Seguindo seu pensamento, você teria que mudar a sua função para que a *variável *disp** recebece o elemento ao invés do valor de um atributo dele, pode fazer isto da seguinte forma:

```
var disp = document.getElementById(divid)
```

Então vc receberia o elemento e ai sim poderia trabalhar em seus atributos, `disp.style.display = 'none'` ou `disp.style.display = "none"` pois JavaScript entende tanto aspas simples quanto aspas duplas como String.

Answer (score 1):

É possível utilizar também, o método `setProperty` da interface `CSSStyleDeclaration`, por exemplo:

```
document.querySelector("element").style.setProperty("display", "none", "important");
```

O último parâmetro é opcional.

Answer (score 0):

Muito simples, fiz com um botão, mas pode ser feito na própria div

```
<script>

function Mudarestado(divid){

 document.getElementById(divid).style.display = "none";

}

</script>

<html>

<div id=1>aaa</div><input type="button" onclick="Mudarestado(1)">

</html>
```

`onclick` na `div`

```
<script>

function Mudarestado(divid){

 document.getElementById(divid).style.display = "none";

}

</script>

<html>

<div id=1 onclick="Mudarestado(1)">aaa</div>

</html>
```

Comment: E Como faço para mudar o texto de um <a href="#">Olá</a> ?

Comment: document.getElementById("IDdoa").href= "link"

Comment: Entendeu como funciona?

Comment: $("#IDdoa").text("TextoAlterado"); somente com JQuery consegui.Acho que era isso que você queria??

Comment: @Nathan130200 Na verdade consegui com document.getElementById("IDdoa").text= "texto que você quiser"!

Answer (score 0):

Usando como referência o nome da class:

```
function ocultaElemento(el) {
        var display = document.getElementsByClassName(el);
        if(display[0].style.display == "none")
           display[0].style.display = 'block';
        else
           display[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```