# Aparecer div para fechar apenas depois de clicar em iframe

Tags: javascript, html

É possível ter uma `div` com um `iframe` e só depois de o usuário clicar num dos links dentro do `iframe`, iria aparecer uma `div` a dizer `fechar` e quando o usuário clicasse ai, fechava a `div` `fechar` e a `div` que continha o `iframe`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalmente eu faço da seguinte forma (sem o uso de iframe), talvez seja interessante para você.
http://jsfiddle.net/zez2n9yb/3/embedded/result/

E agora ele alterado para usar um iFrame:
http://jsfiddle.net/zez2n9yb/9/embedded/result/

Comment: A questao nao é essa amigoo, o que realmente quero é, ex: Tenho um video do youtube e por cima tenho a div a cobrir o video e so quando a pessoa clica na publicidade éq abre outra div a dizer para fechar, entendeu? :ss

Comment: Seguinte, atualizei o exemplo, talvez esteja perto do que deseja.

Comment: É isto mesmo, só que ao clicar num link dentro do iframe aparecia uma div que dizia: Fechar, e ao clicar la, fechava.. É possivel?

Comment: sim, é possível, para tal no lugar de chamar o .confirm(), você teria que tornar esta div visível, dentro desta div teria um button ou input[submit] que fecharia ambas a div e o iFrame.

Comment: fiz uma ultima alteração, quando clicar em um link do iFrame e o mesmo navegar para este link, irá aparecer a mensagem para fechar.
como lhe disse antes, só precisa de uma pequena alteração do script para aparecer uma div no lugar do confirm.

Comment: Pode ajudar-me c isso num jsfiddle se faz favor?  e desculpe :ss

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20819/discussion-between-thecreator-and-tobymosque).

Comment: @thecreator, está ai a alteração que você solicitou:
http://jsfiddle.net/0nh8ms29/1/

Comment: Apenas existem dois problemas amigo, http://jsfiddle.net/0nh8ms29/4/ 1º o background do modal "sobrepoe" o modal e o segundo é: No canto superior esquerdo do iframe tem linkk do facebook, google+ etc.. se clicar num desses links vai para uma pagina exterior, e nao aparece o botao fechar.. o que eu queria era que mesmo que fosse o target = blank, que aparecesse o botao fechar..

Comment: isto é uma limitação do CORS (cross-origin resource sharing), você não pode manipular os elementos de dentro do iFrame quando eles pertencem a outro dominio.

Comment: em vez de `.load`nao posso colocar `.click`?

Answer (score 2):

É possível sim @thecreator.
Para isso você pode usar jQuery. Acho que este [tutorial](http://matheuspiscioneri.com.br/blog/mostrar-e-esconder-elemento-com-jquery/) pode te ajudar.
Veja também esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22735/6942) que trata da mesma questão.

**Atualização**
Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
document.getElementById( 'frame' ).addEventListener( 'click', function( event ){
    $("#Mensagem").show();
})
```

Dentro da DIV mensagem você terá um link ou button que fecha a div que contem o frame.

Comment: Não, nao é a mesma questão. O que estou pretendendo é uma caixa (div) que ira conter um iframe do google (publicidade) e so ao clicar no link de uma dessas publicidade, aparece outro `DIV` a dizer para fechar a caixa (div).

Comment: Entendi, atualizei a resposta. Ve se consegue fazer desse jeito. Pra resolver você precisa "monitorar" o click no frame que é a publicidade. Quando o usuário clicar voce abre outra div dizendo pra fechar a caixa.

Comment: Pode fazer um JSFiddle para me poder ajudar um pouco mais?