# Html DIV ID definida com echo

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou com um problema que não consigo descobrir, não consigo entender porque a ID da DIV não recebe o o valor vindo do php, utilizando o valor da constante `$i`, ele sempre recebe o ultimo valor do laço.
a proposta é mostrar/esconder a DIV selecionada por ID quando clicado no href do Nome.

```
<div class="panel-body">
<?php
//classe
class Clientes{
    public $id;
    public $nome;
    public $cpf;
    public $endereco;

    public function __construct($id,$nome,$cpf,$endereco){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->cpf = $cpf;
        $this->endereco = $endereco;
    }
};

    $cliente1 = new Clientes("0","Bruno","550","rua protasio");
    $cliente2 = new Clientes("1","Thiago","4400", "rua barao");
    $cliente3 = new Clientes("2","Ana","650","rua nova");
    $cliente4 = new Clientes("3","Beatriz","840","rua velha");
    $cliente5 = new Clientes("4","Gustavo","960","rua brasil");
    $cliente6 = new Clientes("5","Alberto","123255","rua jovem");
    $cliente7 = new Clientes("6","Jose","466897","rua normal");
    $cliente8 = new Clientes("7","Andre","44699", "rua das petalas");
    $cliente9 = new Clientes("8","Vinicius","87750", "rua irmao");
    $cliente10 = new Clientes("9","Bruna","4890", "rua bolao magico");

    $arrayclientes = array($cliente1, $cliente2,$cliente3,$cliente4,$cliente5,$cliente6,$cliente7,
                            $cliente8,$cliente9,$cliente10);


    for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    $arrayclientes[$i]->id;
    $arrayclientes[$i]->nome;
    $arrayclientes[$i]->cpf;
    $arrayclientes[$i]->endereco;
    include("thumbimg.php");
    }



    ?>
    </div>
```

Segundo Codigo:

```
<script>
function display()
{
var elem = document.getElementById("disp2");
alert(elem);
if(elem.style.visibility == "hidden"){
    elem.style.visibility="";

} else {
    elem.style.visibility="hidden";
}

} 

</script>
<?php
echo "disp" .$arrayclientes[$i]->id;
?>
<div>
<h4><a onclick="display()"> Nome:<?php echo $arrayclientes[$i]->nome; ?></h4></a>
    <div id=" <?php echo "disp" .$arrayclientes[$i]->id; ?> ">
    <h5>Cpf:<?php echo $arrayclientes[$i]->cpf; ?></h5>
    <p>Endereco: <?php echo $arrayclientes[$i]->endereco; ?></p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: olhe se esta resposta pode te ajudar.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22726/como-esconder-mostrar-uma-div-em-html

Comment: o problema que eu percebi está com a <div id=""> que não recebe o valor, o javascript funciona normalmente

Comment: O segundo código é o que vai no include?

Comment: sim, isso mesmo

Comment: Então veja se a resposta ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o *Segundo Codigo* vai dentro do arquivo `include("thumbimg.php");`.

### Problemas do código:

- A cada loop você está repetindo o `function display() {...}` e em `var elem = document.getElementById("disp2");` você só está chamando o elemento com `disp2`, indepentende do link que você clicar.
- No id de cada elemento você adicionou espaços no começo e fim, `<div id=" <?php echo "disp" .$arrayclientes[$i]->id; ?> ">`, os espaços são considerados caracteres válidos para o ID, portanto se você chamar `document.getElementById("disp2");` ele vai retornar NULL, pois está procurando um ID sem espaço
- Você abre a tag `<h4>`, depois a tag `e fecha``primeiro e depois fecha a tag``, isto está errado:

  ```
  <h4><a onclick="display()"> Nome:<?php echo $arrayclientes[$i]->nome; ?></h4></a>
  ```

  o correto seria assim:

  ```
  <h4><a onclick="display()">Nome:<?php echo $arrayclientes[$i]->nome; ?></a></h4>
  ```

Você resolver o problema, movendo a função para um lugar isolado, fora do arquivo `thumbimg.php` e passar um paramentro no `display()` com o id, veja como pode ser o seu código:

```
<script>
function display(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    alert(elem);
    if(elem.style.visibility == "hidden"){
        elem.style.visibility="";
    } else {
        elem.style.visibility="hidden";
    }
}
</script>

<div class="panel-body">
<?php
    class Clientes {
        public $id;
        public $nome;
        public $cpf;
        public $endereco;

        public function __construct($id,$nome,$cpf,$endereco) {
            $this->id = $id;
            $this->nome = $nome;
            $this->cpf = $cpf;
            $this->endereco = $endereco;
        }
    }

    $cliente1 = new Clientes("0","Bruno","550","rua protasio");
    $cliente2 = new Clientes("1","Thiago","4400", "rua barao");
    $cliente3 = new Clientes("2","Ana","650","rua nova");
    $cliente4 = new Clientes("3","Beatriz","840","rua velha");
    $cliente5 = new Clientes("4","Gustavo","960","rua brasil");
    $cliente6 = new Clientes("5","Alberto","123255","rua jovem");
    $cliente7 = new Clientes("6","Jose","466897","rua normal");
    $cliente8 = new Clientes("7","Andre","44699", "rua das petalas");
    $cliente9 = new Clientes("8","Vinicius","87750", "rua irmao");
    $cliente10 = new Clientes("9","Bruna","4890", "rua bolao magico");

    $arrayclientes = array($cliente1, $cliente2,$cliente3,$cliente4,$cliente5,$cliente6,$cliente7,
                            $cliente8,$cliente9,$cliente10);

    for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
        $arrayclientes[$i]->id;
        $arrayclientes[$i]->nome;
        $arrayclientes[$i]->cpf;
        $arrayclientes[$i]->endereco;

        include("thumbimg.php");
    }
?>
</div>
```

e o segundo código:

```
<?php
echo 'disp', $arrayclientes[$i]->id;
?>
<div>
    <h4>
        <a onclick="display('<?php echo 'disp', $arrayclientes[$i]->id; ?>)">
            Nome: <?php echo $arrayclientes[$i]->nome; ?>
        </a>
    </h4>

    <div id="<?php echo 'disp', $arrayclientes[$i]->id; ?>">
        <h5>Cpf:<?php echo $arrayclientes[$i]->cpf; ?></h5>
        <p>Endereco: <?php echo $arrayclientes[$i]->endereco; ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: já havia testado a questão de espaços, o div id tem que ser dinamica, ou irei esconder TODAS as entradas a moral era esconder apenas uma

Comment: @ThiagoFreitas Então apenas edite a parte do <script>

Comment: eu coloquei aquele valor para verificar se o laço estava atribuindo valor correto para as DIV(por sinal não está), bobeira minha acabei colando o codigo aqui com aquilo.

Answer (score 1):

Retire a função **display** do loop e altere para receber o id por parâmetro.

```
<script>
function display(divId)
{
    var elem = document.getElementById(divId);
    alert(elem);
    if(elem.style.visibility == "hidden"){
        elem.style.visibility="";
    } else {
       elem.style.visibility="hidden";
    }
}
</script>
```

E dentro do loop, passe o ID para função no onclick.

```
<h4><a onclick="display('<?php echo "disp" .$i; ?>')"> Nome:<?php echo $arrayclientes[$i]->nome; ?></a></h4>
    <div id="<?php echo "disp" .$i; ?>">
    <h5>Cpf:<?php echo $arrayclientes[$i]->cpf; ?></h5>
    <p>Endereco: <?php echo $arrayclientes[$i]->endereco; ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olha essas mudanças, só funciona a DIV que ficou com ultimo valor a "DIV 9";

```
<script>
function display()
{
var elem = document.getElementById("<?php echo"disp".$i;?>");
alert(elem);
if(elem.style.visibility == "hidden"){
    elem.style.visibility="";

} else {
    elem.style.visibility="hidden";
}

}

</script>
<?php
echo "disp".$i;
?>
<div>
<h4><a onclick="display()"> Nome:<?php echo $arrayclientes[$i]->nome; ?></a></h4>
    <div id="<?php echo "disp" .$i; ?>">
    <h5>Cpf:<?php echo $arrayclientes[$i]->cpf; ?></h5>
    <p>Endereco: <?php echo $arrayclientes[$i]->endereco; ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

retirei o o ID nos atributos e etc..

Comment: Somente a ultima DIV que mostra/esconde independente de onde eu clicar

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que isso deve resolver o problema:

```
<script>
function display(pos)
{
   var elem = document.getElementById("disp" + pos);
   alert(elem);
   if (elem.style.visibility == "hidden") {
      elem.style.visibility="";
   } else {
     elem.style.visibility="hidden";
   }
} 
</script>
<?php  for($i=0;$i<10;$i++):?>
    <?php
    echo "disp" . $arrayclientes[$i]->id;
    ?>
    <div>
      <h4>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="display(<?php echo $arrayclientes[$i]->id;?>)"> Nome: <?php echo $arrayclientes[$i]->nome; ?></a>
     </h4>
     <div id="<?php echo "disp" .$arrayclientes[$i]->id; ?>">
        <h5>Cpf:<?php echo $arrayclientes[$i]->cpf; ?></h5>
        <p>Endereco: <?php echo $arrayclientes[$i]->endereco; ?></p>
     </div>
   </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```