# Iniciar com div oculta e mostrar com botão

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap-3

Com base na resposta abaixo, criei o botão que exibe e oculta a `div`, mas o que eu gostaria é que a `div` iniciasse já oculta e tivesse um botão para exibí-la. Como poderia fazer?

[Como esconder/mostrar uma div em HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22726/como-esconder-mostrar-uma-div-em-html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com base na resposta mais votada e aceita da questão que tu apresentou, seguem as alternativas de solução, basta adicionar a propriedade `display:none` ao estilo da `div`, utilizando AngularJS `ng-init="MinhaDiv = false"`

**Javascript puro**

```js
function Mudarestado(el) {
  var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
  if (display == "none")
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
  else
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div id="minhaDiv" style="display:none">Conteudo</div>
<button type="button" onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv')">Mostrar / Esconder</button>
```

**Solução em JQuery**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    el = $(this).data('element');
    $(el).toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="minhaDiv" style="display:none">Conteudo</div>
<button type="button" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#minhaDiv">Mostrar / Esconder</button>
```

**Angular JS**

```js
angular.module("ExemploApp", [])
```

```html
<body ng-app="ExemploApp">

  <div id="minhaDiv" ng-init="MinhaDiv = false" ng-show="MinhaDiv">Conteudo</div>
  <button type="button" ng-click="MinhaDiv = !MinhaDiv">Mostrar / Esconder</button>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Perfeito, Obrigado !

Comment: @otaciojb Da uma olhada nesse link https://www.w3schools.com/css/ tem muitas coisas que tu pode fazer com o estilo de qualquer elemento que queira usar.

Comment: Ok, Obrigado Novamente