# Controlar div a partir de um checkbox marcado

Tags: html, angular, checkbox, div

Tenho uma lista de checkbox (*ngFor):

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of listaProcesso">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check" 
    (ngModelChange)="expression && expression[item.name]= $event ? true : undefined"
    [ngModel]="expression && expression[item.name]"
    name="referencia"
    value="{{item.value}}"
    id="{{item.value}}"
    (change)="checkValue(item.value)"
    (change)="onItemChange(item.value)" />
    <!-- (change)="checkValue(item.value)" (change)="onItemChange(item.value) -->
  {{item.name}}
</div>

<div>
  //Esta será controlada
</div>
```

A partir dela, preciso controlar (exibir/ocultar) uma outra div, dado que apenas uma opção deste checkboxes selecionada desta controlaria esta div.
Sou iniciante no

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como esconder/mostrar uma div em HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22726/como-esconder-mostrar-uma-div-em-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este é um exemplo bem simples que renderiza alguns checkboxes. Ao clicar no checkbox o valor do campo `selecionado` dentro do array `listaProcesso` é atualizado. Ao ser atualizado este valor é refletido na lógica do `*ngIf` para mostrar/esconder o div:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of listaProcesso">
   <input 
    type="checkbox"
    [checked]="item.selecionado"
    (change)="item.selecionado = $event.target.checked" /> {{item.label}}
</div>

<ng-container *ngFor="let item of listaProcesso">
  <div *ngIf="item.selecionado">
    {{item.label}}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-boe7qz

Comment: Obrigado, isso me ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 0):

Um outra solução seria:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of listaProcesso">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.value" (change)="isChecked($event)"
         (ngModelChange)="expression && expression[item.descricao]= $event ? true : undefined"
         [(ngModel)]="expression && expression[item.descricao]" name="classificacao"
         value="{{item.value}}" id="{{item.value}}" [checked]="item.selecionado"
         (change)="item.selecionado = $event.target.checked" />
  {{item.name}}
</div>
```

E no arquivo .ts, incluir esta função para o controle:

```html
checkedMarcado: boolean = false;
\\...
  isChecked(valor) {
    if (valor.target.value == 'value do item') {
      if (valor.target.checked) {
        this.checkedMarcado = true;
      } else {
        this.checkedMarcado = false;
      }
    }
  }
```

E por fim na div de controle:

```html
<div class="row" *ngIf="checkedMarcado">
  \\...
</div>
```