# (ReactJS) Ocultar div ao clicar em botão

Tags: javascript, react

Tenho o seguinte código em React:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Join.css';

const Join = () => {

const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [room, setRoom] = useState('');

return (
    <div className="divComponent">
        <div className="divInnerComponent">
            <h1 className="heading">Entre</h1>
            <div><input placeholder="Nome" className="input1" type="text" onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)} /></div>
            <div><input placeholder="Sala" className="input2 mt-20" type="text" onChange={(event) => setRoom(event.target.value)} /></div>
            <Link onClick={event => (!name || !room) ? event.preventDefault() : null} to={`/enter?name=${name}&room=${room}`}>
                <button className="button mt-20" type="submit">Ir</button>
            </Link>
        </div>
    </div>
      )
}
export default Join;
```

Preciso fazer com que, ao usuário clicar no button, a div "divComponent" não seja mais exibida. Como fazer isso? Pensei em alterar o classname da div para um nome que no css já esteja configurado um display:none, mas também não sei como codificar algo assim.

Peço desculpas pela pergunta tão simples, mas é meu primeiro projeto pra valer em React e comecei a estudar a linguagem agora...

Obrigado, amigos!

Comment: Acho que esse post pode te ajudar: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22726/como-esconder-mostrar-uma-div-em-html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22726/como-esconder-mostrar-uma-div-em-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No **componente pai**, **cria um state** para mostrar ou não o o componente:

```
state = { mostrarComponente: false;}
```

**Por padrão será false**, assim o mesmo não será visível.

Feito isso, **crie uma handle** function para quando o click do botão for feito, você o valor para 'true':

```
handleClick() {
    this.setState({
        mostrarComponente: true
    });
}
```

Lembre de **fazer o bind da função no construtor**:

```
constructor() {
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

Agora, dentro do seu **render**, coloque uma condição de renderização:

```
{ this.state.mostrarComponente && <MeuComponente/> }
```